# how to change a running docker container configuration

Tags: docker

I have a run a docker repository that I pulled from the dockerhub. To run this I also added the application properties as part of the docker run command. Now I want to modify those variables.
I have tried changing in the following ***/var/lib/docker/container/<container_name>/config.v2.json***. But this gets overwritten when i tried to start the container

Comment: You can't kill the container and start a new one with the config you want?

Comment: (Imagine changing the command-line arguments of a program you've already started; in most cases you need to stop the program and re-run it with the new arguments.)

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to update container configuration, You're looking for `docker update` command.

  It only works for linux containers.

  Please find below its documentation :

  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/

  For instance :

  `docker update --cpu-shares 512 -m 300M mycontainer`
- If you want to update application configuration, you may use `docker cp`

  Please find below its documentation :

  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

  for instance

  `docker cp host_source_path mycontainer:destination_path`